# querying arcgis and getting results sorted by distance from some point

Tags: javascript, rest, arcgis, esri

Using the REST or javascript api, does anyone know how to get results back sorted by distance from a point?  I'm doing someething like this:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm

and i need the results sorted by distance from the center of a google map.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might could set up a geoprocessing task with the 'Near' Arctool.
and then sorting the result.